# Animate random CSS changes with ngClass

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

I'm trying to "animate" a div's css by choosing a random class at random intervals.  Currently i'm using a recursive function that looks like this:

```js
$scope.spin = function() {
  console.log('spinning');
  var maxCycle = 100;
  var currentCycle = 0;

  recursiveRandomChange();

  function recursiveRandomChange() {
    if (currentCycle <= maxCycle) {
      currentCycle += 1;
      console.log(currentCycle);
      $interval(blockOne(), getRandomTime());
      recursiveRandomChange();
    }
  }

  function blockOne() {
    var currentClass = getRandomClass();
    $scope.engine.one = currentClass;
    console.log('changing color ', currentClass);
  }

};
```

As you can see it only allows for 100 cycles but it's supposed to set "blockOne"s class ($scope.engine.one) to a random class everytime the interval finishes. I can see in the console log the code running correctly but instead of cycling through 100 random classes at random times it only changes once (from the original color to the class randomly picked on the 100th iteration).

Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Share a fiddle or plnkr code for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's needed is `$timeout` not `$interval` as you want to change the color-changing delay period differently each time. And you want to repeat this randomness for 100 times.

`$timeout` is to do it once. `$interval` is to do it multiple times at a fixed interval.

`$interval(blockOne, getRandomTime());` in Ayush's answer doesn't specify how many times `blockOne` will run. Thus, it will run forever..

I [put some logging](http://jsfiddle.net/pfgkna8k/5/) in Ayush code, you will see the random delay period is never changed.

What you really want is chaining 100 `$timeout` so that it runs one after another but not in parallel.

You will need to wrap function around each `$timeout` and then chain them later.

```
var changes = [];
changes[0] =  function() {
    return $timeout(setColor,getRandomTime());
}
changes[1] =  function() {
    return $timeout(setColor,getRandomTime());
}
...
// Chain them

changes[0]()
.then(changes[1])
.then(changes[2]);
```

In this case, you want to chain 100 times. We don't have to type `.then()` 100 times as each `$timeout.then()` is still a promise.

```
var executeChanges = changes[0]().then(changes[1]);
executeChanges = executeChanges.then(changes[2]);
```

I created a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/library/pure/0e15eecab08283f5808a/)

Comment: You, sir, are awesome.  Thank you!  I had noticed the issue with the $interval and have put it on the back burner.  Now its fixed :)  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

check this: http://jsfiddle.net/pfgkna8k/4/ 
Inside recursiveRandomChange, you were recursively calling recursiveRandomChange & using $interval too. $interval is itself recursive.

```
angular.module('lists', []).controller('ProductList', function($scope, $interval) {
    var getRandomTime = function() {
        return 1000;
    };

    $scope.spin = function() {
        console.log('spinning');
        var maxCycle = 100;
        var currentCycle = 0;

        recursiveRandomChange();

        function recursiveRandomChange() {
            if (currentCycle <= maxCycle) {
                currentCycle += 1;
                console.log(currentCycle);
                $interval(blockOne, getRandomTime());
                //recursiveRandomChange();
            }
        }

        function blockOne() {
            var currentClass = getRandomClass();
            //$scope.engine.one = currentClass;
            var element = document.querySelector("#test");
            element.className = currentClass;
            console.log('changing color ', currentClass);
        }

        function getRandomClass() {
            var classes = ["abc", "abc1", "abc2", "abc3"];
            return classes[Math.round(Math.random() * 3)];
        }

    };
    $scope.spin(); 
});
```